# import unittest error

Tags: python, unit-testing

This is my first time doing unit testing and i'm trying to run a simple code...

```
import random
import unittest

class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.seq = range(10)

    def test_shuffle(self):
        # make sure the shuffled sequence does not lose any elements
        random.shuffle(self.seq)
        self.seq.sort()
        self.assertEqual(self.seq, range(10))

        # should raise an exception for an immutable sequence
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, random.shuffle, (1,2,3))

    def test_choice(self):
        element = random.choice(self.seq)
        self.assertTrue(element in self.seq)

    def test_sample(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            random.sample(self.seq, 20)
        for element in random.sample(self.seq, 5):
            self.assertTrue(element in self.seq)

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestSequenceFunctions)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

then i get the error message...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/s66/Desktop/unittest.py", line 2, in <module>
    import unittest
  File "/Users/s66/Desktop/unittest.py", line 4, in <module>
    class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TestCase'
>>>
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 16):

That's because your script name is called `unittest.py`. The statement `import unittest` is importing your script rather than the unittest module, hence the error with the non-existant `TestCase` attribute.

For more info, see the docs for [Module Search Path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path). In short, when you do an import, built-in modules are first searched followed by directories listed in `sys.path`. This usually starts with the location of the running script followed by [`PYTHONPATH`](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) and THEN then default modules directory

In your  case, since `unittest` is not a built-in, it found your script (and loaded it) before it could search for other installed modules.

> How do I fix this?

Rename your script.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a module in the directory where you're running your script that is called unittest.py?

When I run your code I get the following output.

```
test_choice (__main__.TestSequenceFunctions) ... ok
test_sample (__main__.TestSequenceFunctions) ... ERROR
test_shuffle (__main__.TestSequenceFunctions) ... ok

======================================================================
ERROR: test_sample (__main__.TestSequenceFunctions)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 23, in test_sample
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
TypeError: failUnlessRaises() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: The OP's script itself is called `unittest.py`. See file path in traceback.

Comment: Yeah I spotted that after posting, but your answer has it covered, so I just left it.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not intended for this author, but for people that found this stackoverflow page on Google for the same error message but for a different reason.

I was upgrading from django 1.5 to django 1.10, and the "import unittest" in one of my test files was causing a similar error.

The error was due to the app/tests/**init**.py file which was importing the errored test file (this was necessary in django 1.5 as the automatic detection of test files didn't exist at that time. Now it is no longer required).

So the solution was to simply empty the **init**.py file and it solved the issue.

Hope it can help some people as I lost 30mn to 1h on this issue.